# How to incorporate logLoss in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm attempting to incorporate logLoss as the performance measure used when tuning randomForest (other classifiers) by way of caret (instead of the default options of Accuracy or Kappa).

The first R script executes without error using defaults.  However, I get:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "unused argument (model = method)"

when using the second script.

The function `logLoss(predict(rfModel,test[,-c(1,95)],type="prob"),test[,95])` works by way of leveraging a separately trained randomForest model.

The dataframe has 100+ columns and 10,000+ rows.  All elements are numeric outside of the 9-level categorical "target" at col=95.  A row id is located in col=1.

Unfortunately, I'm not correctly grasping the guidance provided by http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html, nor having much luck via google searches.

Your help are greatly appreciated.

Working R script:

```
fitControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",number = 10,repeats = 10)
rfGrid = expand.grid(mtry=c(1,9))
rfFit = train(target ~ ., data = train[,-1],method = "rf",trControl = fitControl,verbose = FALSE,tuneGrid = rfGrid)
```

Not working R script:

```
logLoss = function(data,lev=NULL,method=NULL) { 
lLoss = 0
epp = 10^-15
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    index = as.numeric(lev[i])
    p = max(min(data[i,index],1-epp),epp)
    lLoss = lLoss - log(p)
 }
 lLoss = lLoss/nrow(data)
 names(lLoss) = c("logLoss")
 lLoss
```

}

```
fitControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",number = 10,repeats = 10,summaryFunction = logLoss) 
rfGrid = expand.grid(mtry=c(1,9))
rfFit = train(target ~ ., data = trainBal[,-1],method = "rf",trControl = fitControl,verbose = FALSE,tuneGrid = rfGrid)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should set `summaryFunction=mnLogLoss` in `trainControl` and `metric="logLoss"` in `train` (I found it [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-evaluation-metrics-in-r/)). Like this:

```
# load libraries
library(caret)
# load the dataset
data(iris)
# prepare resampling method
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5, classProbs=TRUE, summaryFunction=mnLogLoss)
set.seed(7)
fit <- train(Species~., data=iris, method="rf", metric="logLoss", trControl=control)
# display results
print(fit)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your argument name is not correct (i.e. `"unused argument (model = method)"`). The [webpage](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html#metrics) says that the last function argument should be called `model` and not `method`.